# Pansharpen Landsat 7 RGB using gdal_pansharpen.py

Tags: gdal, landsat, rgb, landsat-7, pansharpening

Is it possible to pansharpen Landsat 7 RGB band combination (without NIR) to have approximately the same intensities as the original RGB image with gdal_pansharpen.py (weighted Brovey algorithm)?
What is the best way to determine the coefficients?

For example, for Landsat 8 I can achieve such a result after setting weight coefficients <s>[from here](http://blog.remotesensing.io/2013/04/pansharpening-using-a-handy-gdal-tool/)</s> [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200224115934/blog.remotesensing.io/2013/04/pansharpening-using-a-handy-gdal-tool/):

```
gdal_pansharpen.py -w 0.52 -w 0.25 -w 0.23 panchromatic.tif rgb.tif result.tif
```

[image: Landsat 7 wavelengths]