# Pansharpening using GDAL tools

Tags: gdal, pansharpening

I would like to make improvements in the resolution of satellite images using pansharpening. After found [this website](https://medium.com/planet-stories/a-gentle-introduction-to-gdal-part-4-working-with-satellite-data-d3835b5e2971), which explains how Planet Labs do it.

For a University project I would like to try different algorithms for pansharpening, so I could follow that guide but not using the script `gdal_pansharpen.py`. But here I have a problem: I couldn't find the script `gdal_pansharpen.py` so I don't know what is written in there.

I would choose Python for programming the different algorithms (IHS, BT, ...) and see which one is better.

Comment: Gdal_pansharpen.py lives here https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts

Comment: @user30184 Thanks! Is anywhere explained in detail? Because that code without comments or anything is a little bit illegible. How can I know which algorithm do they use, for example?

Comment: Did you read the manual http://www.gdal.org/gdal_pansharpen.html?

Comment: May I suggest you to also look at OTB for other pansharpening tools ?  https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_Pansharpening.html

Comment: @user30184 yes, but that's not what I asked. Maybe I didn't explain it clearly enough. Let me try again: I need the script commented, so I know what each line of code does. Doing that, I can try other algorithms and make a project showing which are the advantages and disadvantages of each one. Thanks!

Comment: @radouxju Thanks, but I don't want a tool. I want to build my own tool, maybe in Python, so I can try different algorithms and see which are the advantages and disadvantages of each one

Comment: I think you should read https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/alg/gdalpansharpen.cpp next. This blog may be useful as well https://medium.com/planet-stories/a-gentle-introduction-to-gdal-part-4-working-with-satellite-data-d3835b5e2971.

Comment: @user30184 the second link you posted is the one I put on the main post. I already read the first one but I find it really difficult to follow because it has no comments, but I'm going to try again

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question when using the `gdal_pansharpen.py` script. I believed GDAL developped their own algorithm... But this post ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240067/pansharpen-landsat-7-rgb-using-gdal-pansharpen-py)) answered your question...

GDAL pan sharpening algorithm = weighted Brovey algorithm

Also specified on Github, line 49 ([here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/alg/gdalpansharpen.h)).